# How to connect wirelessly in a cafe with 11.04

Tags: wireless

Wireless works fine at home.

However, at a cafe I am not able to browse Internet or ping 72.14.204.105.

I am able to connect wirelessly at cafe and ping router: 192.168.1.1.

Route includes:
default   192.168.1.1.  0.0.0.0.   UG      100     0     0      wlan0

I am not using firewall. Using dhcp. No wireless security.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found out the answer.

Ended up removing network manager and using Wicd. Overall Wicd is better, but now I can't connect to iPhone or a different cafe.

Answer (score 3):

That is actually not a problem in Ubuntu, but a problem with the configuration in the cafe. Not all cafes offer free, one click away internet connection. Cafes and Airports for example offer a website to which you connect (Tipically a 192.168.1.1, 10.0.0.1 or similar IPs) and in the web page the charge you with some credit point or credit card the time or bandwidth you will be using. This is one case.

Other cases include a proxy setting that you need to do or some static ip that you need to configure.

In any or all cases you need to ask in the place where you want to connect. Either to the person attending the cafe or if in an airport to somebody in charge.

Mentioning that the wireless connection works in your home just shows that the wireless device in your laptop is working correctly. So the problem must be somewhere else and not in Ubuntu.

Comment: I got it to work with iPad and iPhone. Also, I think it was working there before.

Answer (score 1):

Is your system on Mains Power or Battery when you have the problem or not? I've found that `/usr/sbin/pm-powersave` turns OFF my wireless card when I switch to battery. So far. I've gotten wireless to stay up by executing `sudo /usr/sbin/pm-powersave false`. The `man pm-powersave` page says I can create an empty file `/etc/pm/power.d/wireless` to prevent `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless` from running and doing its magic.

Comment: It's on Mains Power. Same as at home.

Answer (score 0):

Some Cafes reroute you to a "captive" portal where at the very least, you may have to agree to a "terms and conditions" policy.  To get  the portal to appear your may have to search  a fresh URL or hit "home", or clear your cache, so the Access point  can intercept /redirect your fresh request to the captive portal page.  Some portals also provide a walled garden, so you can see cafe ads or menu items  but not access  the whole  web until you have  agreed  to policy.  A local cafe  has  a policy  to issue  half hour session leases,as a "fair"method to knock down clients and give others a chance to log in.  One  Cafe  also revokes  leases more  frequently  during  lunch  periods in hopes turning  over tables  during  lunch time,  and  they inform you of that intent the first  time you login.  Also  some  cafe website portals  are NOT optimized  for mobile devices.  The  agree dialog  can be hard to find if you need  to scroll white space to find a miniscule boxed button or  pull-down control.